# Issue with getHibernateTemplate().get()

Tags: hibernate

I am setting property `Age` after getting object from database as:

```java
Employee emp = getHibernateTemplate().get(Emplyee.class, 1001); 
emp.setAge(25);
```

There are some dependend tables for the above class. So in the middle of the code I got an exception. In the above scenario, `Employee` table is automatically updated. `Employee` table should not be updated if any exception occurs while executing the code. Any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, add the stack trace with an exception.

Comment: got Data Integrity violation exception.Whatever the exception is,please let me know how to handle the issue

Comment: You need to add your persistent classes and an exception from the log to get help.

Comment: Can we prevent that persistence object from updating